# How can I wait for a Particular Pixel's Color to Load?

Tags: multithreading, winapi, win32gui, win32-process, waitformultipleobjects

I am using Win32Api(Windows API) with C/C++.

I am able to take the pixel's RGB color.

```
void WaitForSinglePixel(int x, int y,COLORREF color) //Passing pixel's (X,Y) co-ordinate & the particular Color I need at that pixel.
{
    COLORREF _tempcolor; //in _tempcolor I will assign current color of the pixel at (x,y)
    DWORD Red = GetRValue(color); DWORD Green = GetGValue(color); DWORD Blue = GetBValue(color);
    do //Creating a busy loop
    {
        HDC dc = GetDC(NULL);
        _tempcolor = GetPixel(dc, x, y); //assigning current color of the pixel at (x,y)
        ReleaseDC(NULL, dc);
    } while( (GetRValue(_tempcolor) != Red) & (GetGValue(_tempcolor) != Green) & (GetBValue(_tempcolor) != Blue) );
}
```

But I don't want to make a busy loop. Is there any method or any way to Wait For A Pixel's particular color to load without using busy loop??

Comment: I don't think you can escape some kind of loop, but you can probably take the GetDC/ReleaseDC out of the loop to win some cycles, and at least wait for the vertical sync using D3DKMTWaitForVerticalBlankEvent https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/d3dkmthk/nf-d3dkmthk-d3dkmtwaitforverticalblankevent at each iteration

Comment: I think it is inevitable to use busy loops, but maybe you can use multi-threaded condition variables to reduce the performance loss in busy loops.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API that allows you to register a callback to be called whenever a pixel's color changes.

Comment: How in games people detect change in some pixel and behave according to that change. maybe using busy loops in games will be way too slow!!that means there is some way to avoid busy loop and wait for a pixel color to change

Comment: A busy loop isn't slow. Indeed, busy spinning is the fastest way to respond to a change. It's unclear how you arrived at the conclusion, that a busy loop were slow. It's wasteful, sure, but slow?

Comment: Yes by slow i actually mean inefficient, wasting cpu cycles.